# How can I sort messages received as a thread in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

How can I sort messages datewise that I have received as a thread from a sender in Gmail?  A sender has forwarded me some messages as a thread that are not in chronological order.  I would like to see them in chronological order.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Gmail's messages are not sortable and the order of messages in a thread is chronological based on reception time.

Comment: One could always use a third party email client.